# How Do I use Amazon ElastiCache in grails app?

Tags: java, grails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memcached

I'm very new to Amazon web services and Grails. I want to use Amazon ElastiCache as my cache tool in Grails application.

I searched in google, but I didn't find any resources for it.

Can anybody say me how to configure grails app in order to use elasticache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Grails, so I'd recommend digging into this a bit, but ElastiCache is simply memcached. Have you tried the Grails [memcached plugin?](http://grails.org/plugin/memcached/) The [user guide](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-memcached/docs/manual/guide/2%20Getting%20Started.html) looks quite easy to configure. You'd need to specify the hosts as their AWS URLs and configure the ElastiCache SecurityGroup settings appropriately.